# "Requested keys of a value that is not an object" JSON and React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm having an issue with React Native that I cannot solve, most likely because I'm pretty new to React and JavaScript so I might not have all the "keys". haha

First, this is the structure of my JSON:

```
{ "Spot[]": [
{"id":1,"name": "Relais Villenus"},
{"id":2, "name": "Random"}
]}
```

I did not get to work on a lot of JSON so far but they were never like this and it lost me !

My class requesting the data:

```
class ListScreen extends Component{
static navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Liste',
};

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isLoading: true
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  return fetch(REQUEST_URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Spot),
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

I tried different things based on what I've read here or on GitHub like

```
dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Spot[]),
```

or like this:

```
dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
```

and in the view:

```
renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.Spot.name}</Text>}
```

or

```
renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.Spot[name]}</Text>}
```

My code works with this JSON: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json

This is why I assume the error is because I don't know how to properly fetch the data.

Thanks !

Comment: Try this `ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson['Spot[]'])`

Comment: Oh thank you so much Hassan ! :) It works ! I did try responseJson.['Spot[]']). With a POINT: FML ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing property in the wrong way. Change you `dataSource` to

```
this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson['Spot[]']),
});
```

You need to access your property using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

> Bracket notation expects an expression which evaluates to a string (or can be coerced to a string), so you can use any character sequence as property name. There are no limits to what a string can contain.